# Integrate IBM RTC to worklight for Android App

Tags: android, rtc

I need to develop an Android App which will sync the work-items from RTC Server and show as push notifications to the manager, who can approve, comment or cancel that work-item.

For this, i did explore RTC APIs on jazz.net and integrate its client to Eclipse, after this i also successful in making connection to the Server by using RTC Example provided, So please tell me how can i integrate it into Android App
whether i need to work on eclipse plugin development OR using Plain Java Client Libraries?

and whether i can use worklight for integration and get server rich features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight does not have anything to do with this.
It's just a framework to develop mobile applications.

You need to figure out if RTC provides API to do what you want.
If yes, you need to implement this API in the application.

The communication to the server is done by adapters, assuming that the RTC server has endpoints that allow connecting to.

Comment: Thanks Idan, I find the way by exploring RTC Plain Java Libraries which worked fine in Java Application but when I move its Libraries (jars) to Android Studio for developing mobile App then an exception has come:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
can u guide me from here to move on?